# How to configure CarrierWave in order to upload images to SmartFile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'd like to use SmartFile to upload images for a small Rails web application and need some help with the appropriate configurations to do so by using the CarrierWave gem.

CarrierWave seems to work for many cloud services providers, like AWS S3, Rackspace and Google Storage, but I'm not sure the same goes for SmartFile (by the way, looking to try them out for this small app with CarrierWave as they currently provide free space/usage for developers, but unfortunately have not developed a ruby API). Sample configurations for CarrierWave to be used with S3:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
        # # Configuration for Amazon S3
        # :provider              => 'AWS',
        # :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
        # :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
    }
    # config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
```

If that is not possible with CarrierWave, a solution through a different mature gem (it seems a SmartFile gem was created years back but was not further developed or kept up to date) or the like would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is your actual question? CarrierWave has pretty good [documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3)

Comment: It is as simple as read, how to configure it for use with smartfile? Can you post a code snippet like the one I've shared with the AWS sample that would work with smartfile?